# Unable to run tensorflow code

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Here is the piece of code I cloned off of Github and I am having a hard time getting it to work.

```
def lstm_doc_enc(input_cnn,
               batch_size=20,
               num_rnn_layers=2,
               rnn_size=650,
               max_doc_length=35,
               dropout=0.0):

# lstm document encoder
with tf.variable_scope('LSTMenc') as scope:
    def create_rnn_cell():
        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size, state_is_tuple=True, forget_bias=0.0, reuse=True)
        if dropout > 0.0:
            cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=1.-dropout)
        return cell

    if num_rnn_layers > 1:
        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([create_rnn_cell() for _ in range(num_rnn_layers)], state_is_tuple=True)
    else:
        cell = create_rnn_cell()

    initial_rnn_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)

    input_cnn = tf.reshape(input_cnn, [batch_size, max_doc_length, -1])
    input_cnn2 = [tf.squeeze(x, [1]) for x in tf.split(input_cnn, max_doc_length, 1)]

    outputs, final_rnn_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, input_cnn2,
                                     initial_state=initial_rnn_state, dtype=tf.float32)

return adict(
    initial_enc_state=initial_rnn_state,
    final_enc_state=final_rnn_state,
    enc_outputs=outputs
)
```

I cloned it from the repository of [NeuralSum](https://github.com/cheng6076/NeuralSum).
If I leave reuse=True while creating the BasicLSTMCell, it gives the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pretrain.py", line 358, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "pretrain.py", line 244, in main
    train_model = build_model(word_vocab, train=True)
  File "pretrain.py", line 146, in build_model
    dropout=FLAGS.dropout))
  File "/home/raghuram.vadapalli/styletransfer/NeuralSum/model.py", line 218, in lstm_doc_enc
    initial_state=initial_rnn_state, dtype=tf.float32)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn.py", line 197, in static_rnn
    (output, state) = call_cell()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn.py", line 184, in <lambda>
    call_cell = lambda: cell(input_, state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py", line 713, in __call__
    output, new_state = self._cell(inputs, state, scope)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py", line 241, in __call__
    concat = _linear([inputs, h], 4 * self._num_units, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py", line 1044, in _linear
    _WEIGHTS_VARIABLE_NAME, [total_arg_size, output_size], dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1049, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 948, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 356, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape, use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 341, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 671, in _get_single_variable
    "VarScope?" % name)
ValueError: Variable Model/LSTMenc/rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

If I don't put reuse=True, I get this other error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pretrain.py", line 358, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "pretrain.py", line 251, in main
    valid_model = build_model(word_vocab, train=False)
  File "pretrain.py", line 200, in build_model
    dropout=FLAGS.dropout))
  File "/home/raghuram.vadapalli/styletransfer/NeuralSum/model.py", line 218, in lstm_doc_enc
    initial_state=initial_rnn_state, dtype=tf.float32)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn.py", line 197, in static_rnn
    (output, state) = call_cell()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn.py", line 184, in <lambda>
    call_cell = lambda: cell(input_, state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py", line 235, in __call__
    with _checked_scope(self, scope or "basic_lstm_cell", reuse=self._reuse):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py", line 93, in _checked_scope
    "the argument reuse=True." % (scope_name, type(cell).__name__))
ValueError: Attempt to have a second RNNCell use the weights of a variable scope that already has weights: 'Model/LSTMenc/rnn/basic_lstm_cell'; and the cell was not constructed as BasicLSTMCell(..., reuse=True).  To share the weights of an RNNCell, simply reuse it in your second calculation, or create a new one with the argument reuse=True.
```

I don't have a lot of experience with variable scopes in tensorflow. I tried to google a lot and it came of no use. I hope someone understands what is wrong here and help me.